# Access service and 'self', directly from HTML template?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, service, self

In `Angular 6`, to access our component properties from a service, we pass 'self' to the service from the component. For example:

***myComponent.ts***

```
public myButton;

constructor(private myService: MyService) 
{
    super();
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.myButton = document.getElementById("my-button");
}

saveFunction() {
    var self = this;
    this.myService.myServiceFunction(self)
}
```

***my.service.ts***

```
myServiceFunction(p_self)
{
  ...do stuff
  p_self.myButton.classList.remove("btn-danger");
}
```

This allows us to access the component's button element from a shared service.

A): can I call my service directly from the HTML template?

B): Is there any way to pass `self` to the service from the HTML template? From the HTML I'd like to be able to something like:

***my.component.html***

`<button (click)=this.myService(self)></button>`

Of course, the above does not work - is this just an inherently faulty idea?

Comment: This seems like an Angular anti-pattern. You shouldn't be accessing DOM elements directly unless strictly necessary. Wrap service methods in component methods, and any response you need to send back from the service can be handled in the component.

Comment: If you really want to access the service from the template, why is it `private`?

Comment: Thx @WillAlexander. I guess my thought was to be able to minimize the code in the component, so if I could have it in the HTML template only, it would be nice (rather than having to have a component method that all it does is call the service method). But I guess that's just how Angular works - the `.ts file` is the one that makes the connection to the service (?)

Comment: Services contain business logic, components contain display and interaction logic. Templates should not really contain any logic.

Comment: Keeping it modular in that way allows you to be flexible if you change implementations later.

Comment: Thx @WillAlexander. As for not accessing DOM elements directly - was the reason for this security? You're saying I should stick to built in Angular strategies such as `ViewChild`, etc?

Comment: I don't see any problem with accessing DOM elements directly. But the best way  is to create a method that would be passed an event and then get the element from the event - this is the common and best way. As for accesing services within the template, that's a bad idea. Sometimes we just have to keep writing more code just for the sake of "good logic". For example the way you configured that services within template you're simply passing self, which will not have value because it's only set when saveFunction() is called.

Comment: @KyleVassella You generally don't even need `ViewChild`. Security isn't a problem in this scenario as far as I know. It's more to do with separation of functionality, maintaining maximum modularity and maintainability, and ensuring robust code.

Comment: Here's a good article with some explanations as to the problems that arise when manipulating the DOM directly in Angular. The TL;DR version is that Angular handles things through its own data structures, and those aren't updated if you manipulate things yourself. https://blog.angularindepth.com/working-with-dom-in-angular-unexpected-consequences-and-optimization-techniques-682ac09f6866

Comment: the "above" idea work always you create a variable `self=this` in your component, But you only can access to all the variables of the component. If you has a '@ViewChild` or `@ViewChildren` you can access to these too. Other thing is that is a typical example of **anti-pattern**

Answer (score 0):

You should do the logic in the service and return some output. Then in the component you get that output and based on that you do something with the view. So in your case the flow should be the other way around. From service to component to view.